# Core Data decorating with sort-compare methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have some NSManagedObjects and I would like to write methods for sorting and comparing the properties on them.

My problem is that since Core Data defines the properties as @dynamic they can not be referenced at compile time. This means that decorating an NSManagedObject with methods like this:

```
- (NSComparisonResult) compareDateAndTime:(Event *) event {
    return [originDate compare:[event originDate]];
}
```

will result in the compiler not being able to locate a property called "originDate".
The above method is called like this:

```
NSArray *events = [[NSArray alloc] 
      initWithArray:[unsortedEvents sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compareDateAndTime:)]];
```

I could go with predicates or fetchedResultController, but I would like to build these as
methods myself as I have an identical NSObjects for each NSManagedObject. This NSObject acts as a temp object that is passed around and populated before it's properties are set on the NSManagedObject that is then persisted. I also have some other functions, like specialized accessors, I would like to add to the NSManagedObject.

**(1)**Is there a general/best practice way of decorating NSManagedObjects with methods and functions **(2)**and have Xcode not overwrite them when "re-building" a class for an Entity?

Thank you for any help or "RTFM" given:)

Comment: I answered your questions (1&2) below, but I agree with Frank that I don't understand your "problem" that you initially describe. The compiler should allow you to use the declared properties. Are you including the header of the class generated for the entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I re-generate the model classes for my entities fairly often, so I added support methods (including implementations of getters for transient properties) as "Support" categories on the model classes.

I don't ever have to modify the model class files and there is no way I could accidentally overwrite my additional methods.

For example, a "Place" entity might have a name string and latitude/longitude numbers. It also could have a transient property for the first letter of the name. This can be used as the section name key path for section index titles in a large table view.

Xcode will generate the class files for the "Place" entity like this:

**Place.h:**

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface Place :  NSManagedObject  
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * placeName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * latitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * longitude;

@end
```

**Place.m:**

```
#import "Place.h"

@implementation Place 

@dynamic placeName;
@dynamic latitude;
@dynamic longitude;

@end
```

I create a "Support" category on the "Place" class.

**PlaceSupport.h**:

```
@interface Place (Support)

- (NSString *)uppercaseFirstLetterOfName;
- (CLLocation*)location;

@end
```

and implement it in **PlaceSupport.m**

Comment: Thank you very much Gerry!
Is my face red... I could not get rid of the error from the compiler so I ended up deleting my ManagedObjects, re-build them, close and restart Xcode and suddenly there was no problem accessing the properties. (now I know why I couldn't find this on google or in my Objective C book, there was no problem).

I really like the Category solution, Im not very experienced in Objective C and keep forgetting that subclassing is not always necessary. At least something good came from my question:)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `objectForKey:`?

On the other hand, I haven't had a problem with using the properties directly in my code.

Comment: You are right Frank, I simply ran into some strange Xcode behavior and didn't have the experience to spot there was no proplem:)